# Xamarin forms: How to add SwipeGestureRecognizer for StackLayout?

Tags: xamarin.forms, swipe-gesture, stacklayout

I have 15 options on my home page. Initially, I will show 9 options in UI. To view the remaining 6 icons, the user slides to the right and back to the left to see previous. I try to implement the swiping feature like below, but it is not working.

**XAML**

```
<StackLayout x:Name="firstLlayout">
    <Grid>
        //3 icons in horizontal
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
        //3 icons in horizontal
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
        //3 icons in horizontal
    </Grid>
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Right" Swiped="RightSwipe"/>
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout IsVisible="False" x:Name="secondLayout">
     <Grid>
        //3 icons in horizontal
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
        //3 icons in horizontal
    </Grid>
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Left" Swiped="LeftSwipe"/>
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>
```

**XAML.CS**

```
public void RightSwipe(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    firstLlayout.IsVisible = false;
    secondLayout.IsVisible = true;
}

public void LeftSwipe(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    secondLayout.IsVisible = false;
    firstLlayout.IsVisible = true;
}
```

When try left and right swipe nothing is happening in UI, and code execution not coming to event functions. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cause1:**

Swipe action will conflict with scroll action if you put the stacklayout in a **ScrollView** .

**Solution:**

Remove the ScrollView from Root StackLayout, then the swiping will work.

**Cause2:**  It is necessary to add a child control(like Image or Label)to **StackLayout** , otherwise the swipe action will never been called .

**Solution:** If you do want to let the content of **StackLayout** shows nothing in default, you can check the following code .

#### in code behind

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace xxx
{
    public class GestureScrollView : ScrollView
    {
        public event EventHandler SwipeLeft;
        public event EventHandler SwipeRight;

        public void OnSwipeLeft() =>
            SwipeLeft?.Invoke(this, null);

        public void OnSwipeRight() =>
            SwipeRight?.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

#### in Android Project

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using xxx;
using xxx.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GestureScrollView), typeof(GestureScrollViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class GestureScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        readonly CustomGestureListener _listener;
        readonly GestureDetector _detector;

        public GestureScrollViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _listener = new CustomGestureListener();
            _detector = new GestureDetector(context, _listener);
        }

        public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (_detector != null)
            {
                _detector.OnTouchEvent(e);
                base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
                return true;
            }

            return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
        }

        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            base.OnTouchEvent(ev);

            if (_detector != null)
                return _detector.OnTouchEvent(ev);

            return false;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null)
            {
                _listener.OnSwipeLeft -= HandleOnSwipeLeft;
                _listener.OnSwipeRight -= HandleOnSwipeRight;
            }

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                _listener.OnSwipeLeft += HandleOnSwipeLeft;
                _listener.OnSwipeRight += HandleOnSwipeRight;
            }
        }

        void HandleOnSwipeLeft(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            ((GestureScrollView)Element).OnSwipeLeft();

        void HandleOnSwipeRight(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            ((GestureScrollView)Element).OnSwipeRight();
    }

    public class CustomGestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        static readonly int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        static readonly int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        MotionEvent mLastOnDownEvent;

        public event EventHandler OnSwipeLeft;
        public event EventHandler OnSwipeRight;

        public override bool OnDown(MotionEvent e)
        {
            mLastOnDownEvent = e;

            return true;
        }

        public override bool OnFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
        {
            if (e1 == null)
                e1 = mLastOnDownEvent;

            float diffY = e2.GetY() - e1.GetY();
            float diffX = e2.GetX() - e1.GetX();

            if (Math.Abs(diffX) > Math.Abs(diffY))
            {
                if (Math.Abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.Abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
                {
                    if (diffX > 0)
                        OnSwipeRight?.Invoke(this, null);
                    else
                        OnSwipeLeft?.Invoke(this, null);
                }
            }

            return base.OnFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        }
    }
}
```

And in Xaml

Put the StackLayout in the ScrollView

```
<local:GestureScrollView SwipeRight="RightSwipe">
     <StackLayout x:Name="firstLlayout" >

        //...        
     </StackLayout>

          
</local:GestureScrollView>
```

Comment: Now I noticed that the swiping is not working initially. After trying a couple of times, it starts working. I removed the root stacklayout but still have this issue. Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

I like and used Lucas Zhang's answer [answer-59190549](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59189164/xamarin-forms-how-to-add-swipegesturerecognizer-for-stacklayout#answer-59190549) to this question however, the GestureScrollView can be changed to utilize the same GestureRecognizer's that iOS will use like so:

```
public class GestureScrollView : ScrollView
{
    private bool isInitialized = false;
    private List<SwipeGestureRecognizer> LeftSwipeRecognizers { get; } = new();
    private List<SwipeGestureRecognizer> RightSwipeRecognizers { get; } = new();

    public GestureScrollView() : base()
    {
    }

    protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        base.LayoutChildren(x, y, width, height);

        //Not sure if this is the best place, but the ctor wasn't getting called.
        if (!isInitialized)
        {
            isInitialized = true;
            foreach (SwipeGestureRecognizer swipeGestureRecognizer in GestureRecognizers.Where(x => x is SwipeGestureRecognizer))
            {
                if (swipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.HasFlag(SwipeDirection.Left))
                {
                    LeftSwipeRecognizers.Add(swipeGestureRecognizer);
                }

                if (swipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.HasFlag(SwipeDirection.Right))
                {
                    RightSwipeRecognizers.Add(swipeGestureRecognizer);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteGestureCommands(List<SwipeGestureRecognizer> swipeRecognizers, SwipedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var gesture in swipeRecognizers)
        {
            gesture.SendSwiped(this, e.Direction);
        }
    }

    public void OnSwipeLeft(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExecuteGestureCommands(LeftSwipeRecognizers, e);
    }

    public void OnSwipeRight(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExecuteGestureCommands(RightSwipeRecognizers, e);
    }
}
```

And the Renderer would need changes similar to these (Basically change all "EventArgs" references to "SwipedEventArgs" and pass in a new SwipedEventArgs on the event calls):

```
... 
void HandleOnSwipeLeft(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e) => ((GestureScrollView)Element).OnSwipeLeft(sender, e);
void HandleOnSwipeRight(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e) => ((GestureScrollView)Element).OnSwipeRight(sender, e);
...
public event EventHandler<SwipedEventArgs> OnSwipeLeft;
public event EventHandler<SwipedEventArgs> OnSwipeRight;
...
if (diffX > 0)
{
    OnSwipeRight?.Invoke(this, new SwipedEventArgs(null, SwipeDirection.Right));
}
else
{
    OnSwipeLeft?.Invoke(this, new SwipedEventArgs(null, SwipeDirection.Left));
}
...
```

It's not perfect as it ignores the Up/Down directions in Android, but so does the other implementation.